# django save() method does nothing when called from within a function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having some troubles with Django's save() method.

1 / I have this simple Model :

```
class User (models.Model):
    userId = models.IntegerField()
    appInstance = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

2 / Then in a view, I check if the appInstance does exist and if not I call a function:

```
if not u.appInstance:
    instance = autoAddApplication(request)
```

3 / and autoAddApplication is defined as follows:

```
def autoAddApplication(request):

    session = request.session
    user = get_object_or_404(User, userId = session['user_id'])
    ## do stuff here and end up with an 'instanceMap' dictionary

    user.appInstance = simplejson.dumps(instanceMap)
    user.save()
    return instanceMap
```

The code runs with no error, but I don't get the Model saved in the database when the autoAddApplication function is called from the condition in step 2.

I tried to call this 'autoAddApplication' function directly by mapping a URL diretly to this function and then it does work and I get my Model saved in the DB.

I'm completely puzzled here. Why doesn't it work when I call this 'autoAddApplication' function from within another function ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT
I finally found what I was doing wrong.
Later in step 2 I had a u.save() which was indeed saving u (and therefore overridding the changes I made in the autoAddApplication function).
I solved it by passing along u to the autoAddApplication function.

Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would like you to change `userId` to `user_id`, `appInstance` to `app_instance`, `autoAddApplication` to `auto_add_application` and `instanceMap` to `instance_map`. (And it'd also like you to change `get_object_or_404(User, userId = ...)` to `... userId=...)`.)

Comment: Are you using the correct `User` model? Remember that the built-in user class is also named `User`, you do not import that as well?

Comment: Are you sure that the function is called?

Comment: You might want to check that the user being edited is the user you expect to be edited. You could check this out with a few print statements.

Comment: I don't import Django's built-in user model. I'm sure the function gets actually called and that the user I get from the get_object_or_404 is the right one (did some prints to be sure)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the class name from `User` to `MyUser` or something like that, you may be having troubles with the `User` model defined in Django.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use **autoAddApplication** as a private function inside the view?

```
    def _auto_add_application(session):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, user_id = session['user_id'])
        user.app_instance = simplejson.dumps(instance_map)
        user.save()
        return instance_map
```